# Moving from Google Finance to Yahoo Finance

Tags: canada, portfolio, software, yahoo-finance, google-finance

I have used Google Finance for ages and used to like their interface. I also liked that I'd have easy access to their dashboard from my Google Home page.

I put my transactions in there and it seems to offer a relatively accurate reading of how my portfolio is doing overall.

However, recently it's been really flaky and I've always heard that Yahoo Finance is better. Also, most of my transactions are on the TSE and I find Google Finance doesn't work well with C$ funds. I'm hoping for something more robust. ( Perhaps there's a solution that I haven't thought of? )

What are the steps to moving transaction data and whatnot to Yahoo Finance?

Also, is there any way to automate a withdrawal equivalent to 1/12th of 1% of my portfolio monthly to cover fees from my FA?

Most of my portfolio is ETFs, though I have a few stocks in there as well.

Comment: I have a love hate relationship with wikinvest too.

Comment: You are paying 1%/yr in addition to fund fees or trading costs? And he doesn't give you a clean interface to monitor your holdings?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer There are no trading costs. That's included. No fund fees other than the built-in ER on ETFs. No DSCs. I have an interface to monitor the holdings, but admittedly, it's a poor interface. It shows gains/losses/transactions/etc. but it doesn't show growth over time. In short, it shows how the portfolio is doing NOW overall, but not a historical chart of how the portfolio has gone up and down. I prefer to see how things are visually.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you should use your own tracking software, such as GnuCash, Quicken, Mint, or even Excel.  The latter would work given you say you're manually putting in your transactions.   There's lots of pre-done spreadsheets for tracking investments if you look around.

I'm hoping that a web search gets you help on migrating transaction data, but I've yet to run into any tools to do the export and import beyond a manual effort.  Then again, I haven't checked for this lately.

Not sure about your other questions, but I'd recommend you edit the question to only contain what you're asking about in the subject.